# Unable to bind Contact object to controls without editing the collection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a collection of Contact objects that I've bound as follows in a WPF form:

```
<ComboBox Name="Name" 
      Text="{Binding Path=Contact.FullName}" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding ContactsCollection}" 
      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Contact, Mode=TwoWay}" 
      IsEditable="true" 
      IsTextSearchEnabled="True" 
      TextBoxBase.TextChanged="Name_TextChanged"/>
<TextBox Name="Position" Text="{Binding Path=Contact.Position}"/>
<TextBox Name="Phone" Text="{Binding Path=Contact.PhoneNumber}"/>
```

I'd like the contact to be selected when the user starts typing in the combo 'IsTextSearchEnabled=true'.

The problem is that I'd like the items in the collection to remain read-only. Once a contact has been selected, any text deletes or additions modify the contact name in the collection.

How can I bind a collection to a combobox, enable search and prevent edits to the collection?

Comment: I think you can skip the Mode=TwoWay option in the SelectedItem Binding.

Comment: The underlying objects still change.
Thanks. I think you've pointed out the problem though. 

In my form, I want a contact item that contains the values from the selected contact in the combo and the textboxes. However I don't want the contact collection items to change as values in the textboxes are edited.

So, I think this means that I can't bind to the selected item. Instead I need a contact item separate from the collection.

Comment: What is the `type` of Contact or ContactsCollection

Comment: Contact is a custom object with FullName, Postion and PhoneNumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input. It sorted me out. Removing the SelectedItem property and setting Position and PhoneNumber in the PropertyChanged event was what I needed.

Comment: Or you could just specify a one way binding to avoid using code in a property change.

Answer (score 0):

I could be missing something here, but if you don't want an editable `ComboBox`, try *not* setting the `ComboBox.IsEditable` property to `True`. Using this simple code, I can display items in a `ComboBox` and make selections by typing (when the `ComboBox` is focused) without editing anything:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" Height="25" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'd like an editable ComboBox so that the user can manually enter a contact that is not contained in the collection. I'm pretty sure that my problem is that I shouldn't bind the SelectedItem. In the process of confirming.. :)